# qTip 2 multiple tooltips with AJAX content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using qTip 2 tooltips on my website, with this init code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tooltip').each(function() {
            $(this).qtip({
               overwrite: false,
               content: {
                   text: function(event, api) {
                       $.ajax({
                           url: api.elements.target.attr('source')
                       })
                       .then(function(content) {
                           // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
                           api.set('content.text', content);
                       }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                           // Upon failure... set the tooltip content to error
                           api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                       });

                       return 'Loading..';
                   }
               },
               position: {
                    my: 'bottom left',
                    at: 'top right',
                    viewport: $(window)
               },
               style: 'qtip-tipsy'
            });
        });
    });
```

and HTML Link:

```
<a href="#" id="tooltip" source="http://localhost/php_content">Tooltip</a>
```

This works only for one tooltip with id="#tooltip", is there any way to use this init code for more than one tooltip with same ids and different sources?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There cannot be multiple elements with same IDs. You should use a class instead.

In fact you don't even need a `.each` if I am not wrong. You can do something like this

```
$('.mytooltip-elements').qtip({
  overwrite: false,
  content: {
    text: function(event, api) {
      $.ajax({
          url: api.elements.target.attr('source')
        })
        .then(function(content) {
          // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
          api.set('content.text', content);
        }, function(xhr, status, error) {
          // Upon failure... set the tooltip content to error
          api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
        });
      return 'Loading..';
    }
  },
  position: {
    my: 'bottom left',
    at: 'top right',
    viewport: $(window)
  },
  style: 'qtip-tipsy'
});
```

And add `mytooltip-elements` to the elements which need a tooltip

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/L6yq3/3039/**